# Lectura de fichero de acceso aleatorio en java

Tags: java, archivo, java-8

tengo que hacer una actividad que haga lo siguiente:

Crear una agenda de registros con diferentes datos y guardarlos en un fichero. Recuperar esa información y transformarla a un fichero de acceso aleatorio, el cual tiene que tener dos atributos más, el ID y un booleano que determina si sigue activo o si puede ser borrado, para reemplazar el contenido.

Además, debo implementar dos versiones, una usará readUTF/writeUTF y otra el write normal.

Actualmente llevo esto:
https://github.com/Saito25/Acceso_Datos_Tema_1_Ficheros/tree/master/src/exercise9Perfomenced

(Por favor, obviar el código duplicado y la mala gestión de las clases, el ejercicio me está costando mucho de hacer T-T).

El problema que tengo es que cada vez que inicio la actividad, es decir, cada vez que ejecuto el main, el fichero mide una cantidad de bytes diferentes, oscilando entre 99 y 100... Y no tengo ni idea de por qué.

Además, a veces funciona, a veces no. Y me arroja el error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:803)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.randomFileGenerator.RandomFileOperator.showAllRegistriesInUTFMode(RandomFileOperator.java:85)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.randomFileGenerator.RandomFileOperator.showAllRegistries(RandomFileOperator.java:52)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.randomFileGenerator.utils.RandomFileMenu.showAllRegistries(RandomFileMenu.java:89)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.randomFileGenerator.utils.RandomFileMenu.executeOption(RandomFileMenu.java:68)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.randomFileGenerator.utils.RandomFileMenu.makeElection(RandomFileMenu.java:57)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.randomFileGenerator.utils.RandomFileMenu.showOptions(RandomFileMenu.java:45)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.randomFileGenerator.utils.RandomFileMenu.<init>(RandomFileMenu.java:27)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.randomFileGenerator.RandomFileOperator.<init>(RandomFileOperator.java:40)
    at exercise9Perfomenced.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Ando un poco perdido, como podréis observar en el código. También, no entiendo cómo se calcula los bytes cuando se usa readUTF, con el read normal, creo que es 2 bytes por caracter, no sé si ese sea el problema.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Usando UTF un caracter puede usar un byte, dos bytes, 3 bytes... dependiendo de lo largo que sea su código. Las letras del alfabeto latino necesitan 1 byte, pero si usas acentos o símbolos raros rápidamente pasarás a 2-3 bytes

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, Pablo!